# How to Save the PDF in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, itext

I have created a simple android app to convert a string text into a pdf file. Here is the code. Here I have uses iText library as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static final int STORAGE_CODE=100;
    private Button crBtn;
    private EditText edit;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            crBtn=findViewById(R.id.crBtn);
            edit=findViewById(R.id.edit);
    
    
             crBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            String[] permissions={Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                            requestPermissions(permissions,STORAGE_CODE);
                        }
                        else {
                            savePDF();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        private void savePDF() {
    
            Document mdoc=new Document();
            String mfilename=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    
            String sFilepath=this.getExternalFilesDir("/")+mfilename+".pdf";
    
            try{
                PdfWriter.getInstance(mdoc,new FileOutputStream(sFilepath));
                mdoc.open();
                String mtext=edit.getText().toString();
    
                mdoc.addAuthor("Shashen");
                
                mdoc.add(new Paragraph(mtext));
                
                mdoc.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode){
                case STORAGE_CODE:{
                    if(grantResults.length>0&& grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        savePDF();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have followed a youtube tutorial and followed the instructions to make this code.No, any error is showing in the logcat. But my pdf is not saving to my phone. Can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Which version of itext do you import?  Where is `PdfDocument`?

Comment: @Bottle, from the look of the API, for some reason they are using iText 5

Comment: add debug or sysout lines inside onClick() against if loops and see how code flows